# How to send a variable from javascript to html?

Tags: javascript, django

I would like to fill a table by data from database. I am developing my project using Django. However,
required data are based on select elements (depended select), that why I used JavaScript to get data from database.
I was able to get required data with JavaScript:

```
const engineInput = document.getElementById('select_eng')
const btnBox = document.getElementById('btn-submit')
const aircraftForm = document.getElementById('ac-eng-form')
const csrf = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')
const flighInput = document.getElementById('flights')
const tablePrint = document.getElementById('table_with_data')


aircraftForm.addEventListener('submit', e=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('submittted')
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/show-data/',
        data: {
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf[0].value,
            'engine': engineInput.value,
            'flights': flighInput.value,
        },
        
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response)
            tablePrint.innerHTML = response
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
})
```

Now, I want to transfer data from JSON response to HTML **as a variable "table"**. How can I do this?
I don't want to fill a table using JavaScript, instead I want to use a template engine.

```
<table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">Flight</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Date</th>
                <th colspan="2">Oil quantity, %</th>
                <th colspan="2">Oil temperature, %</th>
                <th rowspan="2">dt, hr</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Engine FH</th>
                <th colspan="4">Oil Consumption, Quarts/hr</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Qa</th>
                <th>Qb</th>
                <th>Ta</th>
                <th>Tb</th>
                <th>QH, raw</th>
                <th>Average for 10 flights</th>
                <th>Average for 20 flight</th>
                <th>Average for 30 flight</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="table_with_data">
            {% for row in table %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{row.Flight_Num}}</td>
                <td>{{row.Flight_Date}}</td>
                <td>{{row.Oil_Quantity_Departure}}</td>
                <td>{{row.Oil_Quantity_Arrival}}</td>
                <td>{{row.Oil_Temperature_Departure}}</td>
                <td>{{row.Oil_Temperature_Arrival}}</td>
                <td>{{row.Flight_Time}}</td>
                <td>{{row.Engine_TSN}}</td>
                <td>{{row.Oil_Cons_Current_Flight}}</td>
                <td>{{row.Oil_Cons_10_Flights}}</td>
                <td>{{row.Oil_Cons_20_Flights}}</td>
                <td>{{row.Oil_Cons_30_Flights}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="12">* Oil Consumption limit IAW AMM is 0.25 quart/h</td>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

Here is my view function where data from database are sent to JSON response

```
def get_eng_sn(request):
    if is_ajax(request=request):
        engine = request.POST.get('engine')
        flight = int(request.POST.get('flights'))
        data_to_table = Engine.objects.filter(Ser_Num=engine).order_by('-id')[:flight].values()
        return JsonResponse(list(data_to_table), safe=False)
    return JsonResponse({'result': False})
```

Thanks @Waldemar Podsiadło for the advice! How I solved it:

1. How I change view function

```
    def get_eng_sn(request):
        if is_ajax(request=request):
            engine = request.POST.get('engine')
            flight = int(request.POST.get('flights'))
            data_to_table = Engine.objects.filter(Ser_Num=engine).order_by('-id')[:flight].values() 
    context = {
                'table': data_to_table,
            }
            return render(request, 'oilcons/table.html', context)
```

2. How I changed HTML file:

   ```
    <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="2">Flight</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">Date</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Oil quantity, %</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Oil temperature, %</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">dt, hr</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">Engine FH</th>
                    <th colspan="4">Oil Consumption, Quarts/hr</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Qa</th>
                    <th>Qb</th>
                    <th>Ta</th>
                    <th>Tb</th>
                    <th>QH, raw</th>
                    <th>Average for 10 flights</th>
                    <th>Average for 20 flight</th>
                    <th>Average for 30 flight</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="table_with_data">

                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="12">* Oil Consumption limit IAW AMM is 0.25 quart/h</td>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
   ```

   3. New separate HTML file:

```
    {% block table %}
    <table id="table_with_data">
                <tbody>
                {% for row in table %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{row.Flight_Num}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.Flight_Date}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.Oil_Quantity_Departure}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.Oil_Quantity_Arrival}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.Oil_Temperature_Departure}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.Oil_Temperature_Arrival}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.Flight_Time}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.Engine_TSN}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.Oil_Cons_Current_Flight}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.Oil_Cons_10_Flights}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.Oil_Cons_20_Flights}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.Oil_Cons_30_Flights}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
    {% endblock %}
```

I hope there is nothing wrong to it this way.

Comment: If you want to do it nicely, use a SinglePageApplication library like Angular. Or just parse the html code yourself.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-qaxpal?file=script.js

Comment: Thank you for your code, it too complicated, though. Is there other simpler solution for my problem?

Comment: Use htmx. Move your table template to separate html file and return it to div with hx-post on form. No js needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually it helped. Indeed, I just put table in the separate HTML file and sent (return) HTML code to <tbody>.   ` return render(request, 'oilcons/table.html', context)`, where "context" is a Queryset.